# Javascript currency formatting

Tags: javascript, formatting, currency

I'm having a pesky issue...

I'm using a small javascript to format currency such as

2990 to 2.990 and 129900 to 129.900 using the current line:

```
var wdiscount2 = wdiscount.toFixed(3);
```

However, when I have a number under 1000 such as 789 it displays like 0.789

Do you have a way for me to get around this easily?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using a library, such as [accounting.js](http://josscrowcroft.github.com/accounting.js/) from Joss Crowcroft is a good idea? It supports all kinds of formats and is used by quite a few people I believe.

```
wdiscount2 = accounting.formatMoney(wdiscount)
```

Comment: Tried that, still having the same issue with this plugin

Comment: Have you checked out all of the different formatting options?

Answer (score 1):

```
 var wdiscount2 = wdiscount > 999 ? wdiscount.toFixed(3) : wdiscount;
```

Comment: Odd, this gives me from 728 to 0.728999999999

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the questions may already be answered, but there is another alternative, which might be interesting, namely use of regular expressions.

Example:

```
var num  = 2990;
var formattedNumber = num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})(?!\d))/g, "$1.")
```

A few test cases (`num` on the left, `formattedNumber` on the right):

- `2990` => `2.990`
- `129900` => `129.900`
- `789` => `789` (no `.` for this one)

I hope that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is to use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```
const formatCurrency = (num, locale = 'en-US', currency = 'USD', minimumFractionDigits = 2) => {
    if (isNaN(num)) {
        return num;
    }
  return num.toLocaleString(locale, {style: 'currency', currency, minimumFractionDigits});
};
```

Here is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oob68ef1/)